# Просто фидбэк с#

Tags: c#

Нету знакомых кто мог бы понять и запустить, но очень хочется с кем-то поделиться!
Учусь пару недель, пока прошел только массивы и циклы, да и этого было достаточно, чтобы сделать, что-то интересное. Было бы неплохо найти кого-нибудь, кто посмотрел бы на все это и сказал то, что думает по этой штуке. Спасибо.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace miniGame
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.CursorVisible = false;
            Console.WindowHeight = 35;
            Console.WindowWidth = 160;
            Console.WriteLine("Короче, это микро игра основана на рандоме. Так что если тебе сгенерировало беспобедный варик, то тебе не повезло.");
            Console.WriteLine("Игрок 'Я' должен каким-то образом попасть к победе 'W'. ");
            Console.WriteLine("На карте в рандомном месте (недалеко от игрока) геренируется кирка 'K' которая может ломать стены.");
            Console.WriteLine("двигаться на 'WSDA' пользоваться киркой на 'пробел'.");
            Console.WriteLine("Нажми что-нибудь чтобы продолжить");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("ЗАГРУЗКА...");
            Thread.Sleep(1500);
            Console.Clear();
            Random rand = new Random();
            char[,] playground = new char[30, 150];
            for (int i = 0; i < playground.GetLength(0); i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < playground.GetLength(1); j++)
                {

                    if (i == 0 || i == playground.GetLength(0) - 1)
                    {
                        playground[i, j] = '#';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        playground[i, j] = ' ';
                    }
                    if (j == 0 || j == playground.GetLength(1) - 1)
                    {
                        playground[i, j] = '#';
                    }
                }
            }
            for (int i = rand.Next(0, 3); i < (playground.GetLength(0) - 1); i += rand.Next(1, 7))
            {
                for (int j = rand.Next(0, 3); j < (playground.GetLength(1) - 1); j += rand.Next(15, 30))
                {
                    int wallLenght;
                    int direction = rand.Next(0, 5);
                    if (direction <= 1)
                    {
                        wallLenght = rand.Next(3, 20);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        wallLenght = rand.Next(10, 25);
                    }
                    switch (direction)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            int counter = 0;
                            for (int k = 0; k < wallLenght; k++)
                            {
                                counter++;
                                if (i <= 0 || i >= (playground.GetLength(0) - 1) || j <= 0 || j >= (playground.GetLength(1) - 1))
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    playground[i, j] = '#';
                                    i++;
                                }
                            }
                            i -= counter;
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            int counter1 = 0;
                            for (int k = 0; k < wallLenght; k++)
                            {
                                counter1++;
                                if (i <= 0 || i >= (playground.GetLength(0) - 1) || j <= 0 || j >= (playground.GetLength(1) - 1))
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    playground[i, j] = '#';
                                    i--;
                                }
                            }
                            i += counter1;
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            int counter2 = 0;
                            for (int k = 0; k < wallLenght; k++)
                            {
                                counter2++;
                                if (i <= 0 || i >= (playground.GetLength(0) - 1) || j <= 0 || j >= (playground.GetLength(1) - 1))
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    playground[i, j] = '#';
                                    j--;
                                }
                            }
                            j += counter2;
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            int counter3 = 0;
                            for (int k = 0; k < wallLenght; k++)
                            {
                                counter3++;
                                if (i <= 0 || i >= (playground.GetLength(0) - 1) || j <= 0 || j >= (playground.GetLength(1) - 1))
                                {
                                    break;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    playground[i, j] = '#';
                                    j--;
                                }
                            }
                            j += counter3;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            int playerX = 2, playerY = 2;
            int spudX = rand.Next(1, playground.GetLength(1) - 115);
            int spudY = rand.Next(1, playground.GetLength(0) - 15);
            int spud = 0;
            int win = 0;
            playground[spudY, spudX] = 'K';
            playground[playground.GetLength(0) - 2, playground.GetLength(1) - 2] = 'W';
            while (win == 0)
            {
                playground[playerY, playerX] = 'Я';
                for (int i = 0; i < playground.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < playground.GetLength(1); j++)
                    {
                        Console.Write(playground[i, j]);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                }
                ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey();
                switch (key.Key)
                {
                    case ConsoleKey.W:
                        if (playground[playerY - 1, playerX] != '#')
                        {
                            if (playground[playerY - 1, playerX] == 'W')
                            {
                                win++;
                            }
                            if (playground[playerY - 1, playerX] == 'K')
                            {
                                spud++;
                            }
                            playerY -= 1;
                            playground[playerY + 1, playerX] = ' ';
                        }
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.S:
                        if (playground[playerY + 1, playerX] != '#')
                        {
                            if (playground[playerY + 1, playerX] == 'W')
                            {
                                win++;
                            }
                            if (playground[playerY + 1, playerX] == 'K')
                            {
                                spud++;
                            }
                            playerY += 1;
                            playground[playerY - 1, playerX] = ' ';
                        }
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.A:
                        if (playground[playerY, playerX - 1] != '#')
                        {
                            if (playground[playerY, playerX - 1] == 'W')
                            {
                                win++;
                            }
                            if (playground[playerY, playerX - 1] == 'K')
                            {
                                spud++;
                            }
                            playerX -= 1;
                            playground[playerY, playerX + 1] = ' ';
                        }
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.D:
                        if (playground[playerY, playerX + 1] != '#')
                        {
                            if (playground[playerY, playerX + 1] == 'W')
                            {
                                win++;
                            }
                            if (playground[playerY, playerX + 1] == 'K')
                            {
                                spud++;
                            }
                            playerX += 1;
                            playground[playerY, playerX - 1] = ' ';
                        }
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.Spacebar:

                        if (spud == 1)
                        {
                            if (playerX != 1 && playerY != 1)
                            {
                                playground[playerY - 1, playerX - 1] = ' ';
                            }
                            if (playerX != 1)
                            {
                                playground[playerY, playerX - 1] = ' ';
                            }
                            if (playerX != 1 && playerY != playground.GetLength(0) - 2)
                            {
                                playground[playerY + 1, playerX - 1] = ' ';
                            }
                            if (playerY != playground.GetLength(0) - 2)
                            {
                                if (playground[playerY + 1, playerX] == 'W')
                                {
                                    win--;
                                }
                                playground[playerY + 1, playerX] = ' ';
                            }
                            if (playerX != playground.GetLength(1) - 2 && playerY != playground.GetLength(0) - 2)
                            {
                                if (playground[playerY + 1, playerX + 1] == 'W')
                                {
                                    win--;
                                }
                                playground[playerY + 1, playerX + 1] = ' ';
                            }
                            if (playerX != playground.GetLength(1) - 2)
                            {

                                if (playground[playerY, playerX + 1] == 'W')
                                {
                                    win--;
                                }

                                playground[playerY, playerX + 1] = ' ';
                            }
                            if (playerX != playground.GetLength(1) - 2 && playerY != 1)
                            {
                                playground[playerY - 1, playerX + 1] = ' ';
                            }
                            if (playerY != 1)
                            {
                                playground[playerY - 1, playerX] = ' ';
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case ConsoleKey.E:
                        break;
                }
                Console.SetCursorPosition(0, 0);
            }
            switch (win)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.Clear();
                    Thread.Sleep(1500);
                    Console.WriteLine("Изи катка");
                    Thread.Sleep(1500);
                    Console.WriteLine("Победка");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;
                case -1:
                    Console.Clear();
                    Thread.Sleep(1500);
                    Console.WriteLine("Зачем ты сломал победу?");
                    Thread.Sleep(1500);
                    Console.WriteLine("Ну ты и голова!");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Начинание супер, молодцы, ну а код ужасный, так называемый "спагетти" код, где намешено все в одну кучу, в один метод, с тонной дублирований. И да, непонятно что вы хотите от нас, если "инспекцию кода", то вешайте соответствующую метку, если про "задумку", то как по мне, такому не место на SO, ибо пользы для других нет.

Comment: Если каждый чел, который только начал изучать программирование будет сюда кидать свои поделки и достижения - этот ресурс превратится в помойку, а не в базу знаний, коим и должен быть.

Comment: Если вам приходится писать повторяющийся код, значит уже что-то пошло не так. Разбивайте код на методы.

Comment: Минусы за вопрос вы очевидно получили совсем не за качество кода, а потому что даже не написали, что этот код делает или должен делать. Что это за "штука"? Отвечающий сам должен разобраться/угадать? Также вы нажали кнопку "Задать вопрос" и не задали его. В этом вопросе не хватает вопроса. [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Как по мне для начала это очень хорошо, даже отлично. Тут вы показываете свой уровень владения циклами и массивами, что достаточно хорошо, а так же отлично ориентируетесь в коде (Судя по его размерам)

Дальше попробуйте упростить ваш код, изучайте дальше методы и как с ними работать, вынесите соответствующие куски кода в методы и увидите разницу

Comment: Если уж вы решились вровести ревью кода, в ответе следует указать на проблемы конкретно с примерами и предложить варианты улучшения. А пока это не ответ на поставленный вопрос, а просто похлопали в ладоши и ничего не предложили. Зачем методы? Куда методы? Для чего? Разницу чего с чем надо увидеть?

Comment: @aepot я ведь тут не репетитором пришёл работать. Думаю, если человек начнёт изучать методы, он сам уже додумается куда их вставлять, либо задаст другой вопрос по этому поводу. Какую "базу знаний" пополнит частный случай использования методов? Ну я могу ему его игру на Unity сделать, будете делать верью? Или в библиотеку закинете?

Comment: Тогда не было смысла отвечать, могли просто написать комментарий. [Как написать хороший ответ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: @aepot, чем ответ отличается от комментария? По всем параметрам, это больше всё же похоже на ответ, чем на комментарий

Comment: Спасибо, друг. Возможно есть какой-то другой форум, где я мог бы делиться своими стараниями, и не тратить время "серьезных" ребят своими шутками?

Comment: @slavavorobev, есть, но это будет считаться рекламой, но этому ищите )